# C# generics extension method issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, model

I'm fairly new to writing generic transform model extensions and I was trying to go from a model to an Azure service bus message which works as expected. But I'm now trying to do the reverse where it can go from a message to a specified type.

The extension method currently looks like so:

```cs
    public static class ModelExtensions
    {
        public static Message ToMessage<TModel>(this TModel model) =>
            new Message(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)));

        public static TType FromMessage<TModel, TType>(this TModel model)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TType>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do the reverse of what I have just done to many types depending what is specified on the other side of the extension method for example if on the outside I have done something like:

```
message.FromMessage<SpecificType>()
```

Comment: ToMessage() does not need to be generic since you're not using `TModel` anywhere within the method body. You can just take in `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
public static TModel FromMessage<TModel>(this Message message)
  => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TModel>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));
```

**Usage**

```
var result = message.FromMessage<MyLovelyHorse>()
```